# How to check/monitor/log Servlet memory usage on Windows?

Tags: monitoring, tomcat, java, memory-usage, servlet

I've notices several topic on how to check the memory usage of Java application on linux, but I can hardly find anything, even on Google, about a quick and easy way to perform such a check on Windows.

The situation is, I've got Tomcat up and running as the Java Servlet container, inside which a Servlet is running and listening on port 9300. How can I check/monitor/log its memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been enabling JMX in my Tomcat instances, then running VisualVM.  Just add the following parameters to the Java Options using the Tomcat configuration tool (it's an icon in the system task tray).

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/jmxremote.password
```

Then use VisualVM to connect to "localhost:8004".

VisualVM comes with the latest JDK's but is also available here:
https://visualvm.dev.java.net/

As an alternative, I just started working with Psi Probe (it's a fork of Lambda Probe) and really like it.
http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to configure LambdaProbe

http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm

Comment: I looked at LambdaProbe and it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.  Thought the forked offering Psi Probe was better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to tell you there's a freeware software for windowns which can properly help you. 
It's called Capsa Free. I war redirected to their website by techrepublic, you can google it.